# KendoUI - AutoComplete does not open the dropdown with Web browser Control

Tags: autocomplete, kendo-ui, webbrowser-control

Got a simple KendoUI - AutoComplete control on a web page. When I open the page in stand-alone browser (IE-11), it works fine. When I open the page in web browser control (embedded in the win form application), the autocomplete is not opening a dropdown (in the example below, the 'some' alert does not fire. Change event works fine in both scenario, though). The Web Browser control is in IE-11 browser emulation mode.

```
        <div>
        <input id="autoComplete" />
        </div>

    var dataA = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"];
    $("#autoComplete").kendoAutoComplete({
     dataSource: dataA,
     open: function (e) {
        alert('some');
     },
     change: function (e) {
        var value = this.value();
        alert(value);
        // Use the value of the widget
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The core of problem was, the special keys (TAB, ENTER etc) were not working and so the autocomplete control was not getting keys related events. The culprit turned out to be the VCLhook. The delphi application was loading a COM+ dll in the main kernal container. This DLL contained a form with the web browser control(TWebBrowser). The main kernal container, in which the COM+ dll was loaded, was setting the IsVCLHook (Controls.pas) to TRUE. The problem got resolved, when we set that to FALSE for the dll that contained the web browser control (TWebBrowser).